# $n^2+n+1$ is not prime if $n$ is a perfect square $>1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In searching for primes of the form $n^2+n+1$, why should one omit as choices of $n$ those integers that are perfect squares?

I know that the form $Ak+B$ contains infinitely many primes if $\gcd(A,B)=1$, $k=0,1,2...$.

$n^2+n+1 = n(n+1)+1$, so it is in the above form. I know that perfect squares do not give prime in this form when I put each term. Please explain.

Comment: Just a small useful hint for the future: Let $k^2$ be a perfect square, then plug it instead of $n$ to get $k^4+k^2+1$, then put it on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k^4%2Bk^2%2B1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I like such formulae more when they are expressed in terms of cyclotomic polynomials, so I restate here the solution, although  Peter has already provided it before.*

For $n=1$ it is trivially $n^2+n+1 = 3 $ but also $n^4+n^2+1 = 3$ which sums are both times primes.
But for $n>1$ we can always write in the form of cyclotomic polynomials
$$ 1+ n + n^2 =  { n^3-1\over n-1 }  $$ 
Now let $n=m^2$ be some square-number $>1$. Then
$$ { m^6-1\over m^2-1 } ={ m^3-1\over m-1 }\cdot{ m^3+1\over m+1 } \\
$$
and both factors of the latter product are integers, each bigger than $1$ thus their product is composite ( - here I use my "automatic" knowledge, that cyclotomic polynomials ${a^m+1\over a+1}$ with odd $m$ are always integer because then $a^m+1$ has the algebraic factor $a+1$) .

Answer (score 7):

$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)$$, so $n^4+n^2+1$ is not prime for $n\ge 2$